# Adding a sortcomparefunction to Dynamic Data Grid in flex

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, datagrid, sortcomparefunction

I am trying to create a dynamic datagrid in Flex 3, I have a list of columns a list of objects which correspond to datapoints for those columns which I fetch from a url. While the grid works perfectly fine the problem is that sorting on the columns is done in lexical order.

I am aware that this can be fixed by adding a sortcomparefunction to a column, which is not easy for this case. I have tried doing

```
            var dgc:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn(dtf);
            f1[dtf] = function(obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int {
               return Comparators.sortNumeric(obj1[dtf],obj2[dtf]);
            };
            dgc.sortCompareFunction = f1[dtf];`
```

But the problem is that the function object that I am creating here is being overwritten in every iteration (as I am adding columns) and eventually all the columns will have sorting done only on the last column added.

Suggestions please.

Comment: I don't understand why your sortCompareFunction would be overwritten.  Can you expand the question with a more in depth code sample?

Comment: I have a list of columns, when I add sortcomparefunction to this table in the way above, the resulting table has sorting on only the last column. My hunch is that the function is being overwritten each time, only the last one survives and so when I am sorting on a column the whole table behaves as if I was sorting on the last one

Comment: The code above is too generic to give me a pciture of what's going on.  It makes references to a lot of things without explaining any of them (f1, dtf, obj1, obj2, etc.. ). To my knowledge there is no ;"comparators" class, either.  I highly doubt that adding a new column to a DataGrid would overwrite the SortCompareFunction on a different column. I believe something else is going on; but haven't the foggiest idea what. Can you provide a running sample?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Let me clarify
1. The Comparators class is the one I added, it basically provides functions for comparing different datatypes
2. I could get around the problem by making the class comparators non static and by providing parameters on which to compare to the class constructor
3. So, the problem wasnt that the function was getting overwritten but the fact that a reference to one variable 'dgc' in this case was getting overwritten.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you have dynamicColumns array of some objects that you want create datagrid columns from.

```
var columns:Array = new Array();    
for (var i:int = 0; i < dynamicColumns.length; i++) {
    var column:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn(dynamicColumns[i].label);

    var dataGridColumnSortingHelper:DataGridColumnSortingHelper = new DataGridColumnSortingHelper(column);
    column.sortCompareFunction = dataGridColumnSortingHelper.columnSortCompareFunction;
    columns.push(column);
}
yourDataGrid.columns = columns;
```

Where DataGridColumnSortingHelper is like this:

```
public class DataGridColumnSortingHelper
{
    private var column:DataGridColumn;

    // Constructor
    public function DataGridColumnSortingHelper(column:DataGridColumn)
    {
        this.column = column;
    }

    // Public Methods
    public function columnSortCompareFunction(item1:Object, item2:Object):int
    {
        // define your custom function here and use column field to know what column you sorting by...

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks Tom for comment.